# Triple product value given the following conditions:

Tags: linear-algebra

So on our linear algebra exam today we had to find the value of the triple product

$$(a \times b) \cdotp c$$

with the following conditions:

- $|a| = 3, |b| = 2, |c| = 1$
- the angle between a and b is 30°
- the angle between the vector c and the plane given by vectors a and b is 60°

The official solution is only $3\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$, and while I agree that is one solution, I would also argue that $-3\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ is another solution.

My reasoning is that there exist two vectors c that have a 60° angle with the given plane. One of those, the one that the official solution considers, would face the same direction as $a \times b$, giving a positive value of the triple product. The angle between them is in this case 30°.

The other such vector, however, faces the opposite direction, away from $a \times b$, with an angle between them of 150° - giving a negative value of the triple product.

Another way to look at it is that we can swap the positions of the vectors a and b. This would give the exact same plane, and the angle between them would be the same, but $a \times b$ would face the opposite direction - again giving a different value of the triple product.

Is there something wrong in my logic or is the official solution wrong?

Comment: Your solution is better